# How to check enctype at the MVC Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to check at the controller action to see if the data are posted from a `enctype="multipart/form-data` form? How?

---

Update: I got a form with file upload.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Report", FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    ....
}
```

On the controller, to accept the POST.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(InputModel model){
....
}
```

Is there anyway we can tell if the data posted to this action is from a `multipart` enctype form or a regular form?

Say, there is a regular form on another page, which has no file upload. It wants to post to the same action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that good idea, but you can try it.

Add a hidden property at the View like

`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.HiddenPropertyName)`

then check the value at controller

```
if(model.HiddenPropertyName == "someValue")
  // upload file or something
 else
  // do your work
```

Comment: So your answer is there is no way we can check the original form the data posted from. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, there is no way we can check the original form the data posted from.